Infinite sums and closure of linear subspace generated by finite linear combinations of orthonormal set in Hilbert Space
If we have an orthonormal set $(\phi_k)_{k = 1}^{\infty}$ in a Hilbert Space H and we set $M = \overline{\text{lin}}(\phi_1, \phi_2, ...)$ (that is, the closure of the set of all finite linear combinations of $\phi_k$'s), it is easy to se that if $u = \Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty} \alpha_k \phi_k$ then $u \in M$. Is the other way true? If $u \in M$, can we write $u$ as $\Sigma_{k = 1}^{\infty} \beta_k \phi_k$ for some real $\beta_k$'s?

It is true. The set ${\phi_n}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\overline{M}.$ Hence every element $u\in \overline{M}$ admits the representation $\sum\beta_n\phi_n,$ where $\sum \beta_n^2<\infty.$
